# Selecting SQL DateTime with C# DateTime variable

Tags: c#, mysql, database, datetime, formatting

I'm trying to run a query that selects all from a table that contains a DateTime. At the DateTime, it uses a DateTime variable (argument passed through the parameter), however it gives me this exception:

"**FormatException was unhandled**
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The string was not recognized as a valid datetime"

**Solutions I've tried, but didn't work:**

- Convert the DateTime to string
- Convert the DateTime to string with correct format and then back to
  DateTime again
- Use the DateTime.Parse method
- Use the DateTime.ParseExact method with correct format and using both
  "CultureInfo.InvariantCulture" and "CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB")
- Change the format to the exact same shown when running the query in
  Database

As said, none of the above have worked..

- The format I try to use: "MM/dd/yyyy 00:00:00"
- Format shown when running query in database: "MM/dd/yyyy
  hh:mm:ss:fff" (the time needs to be set to 00:00:00)

**Here is the code with the connection stuff excluded:**

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Arithmetics "
                    + "INNER JOIN ArithmeticsAndTypeIDs "
                    + "ON Arithmetics.ArithmeticID = ArithmeticsAndTypeIDs.ArithmeticsID "
                    + "INNER JOIN ArithmeticTypes "
                    + "ON ArithmeticsAndTypeIDs.TypeID = ArithmeticTypes.TypeID "
                    + "WHERE UserID = @value1 "
                    + "AND TimeStamp >= '@value2' "
                    + "AND TimeStamp <= '@value3'", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", GetUserID(userLoggedIn));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", DateTime.ParseExact(time.ToString(), formatString, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB").DateTimeFormat));
                time = time.AddDays(1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value3", DateTime.ParseExact(time.ToString(), formatString, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB").DateTimeFormat));
```

The problem first occurs at the line: "+ "AND TimeStamp >= '@value2' ""

*** And in case it makes a difference, here is the quote I use in the database which obv. works (with the variables replaced by placeholder values)**

```
    SELECT * FROM Arithmetics
    INNER JOIN ArithmeticsAndTypeIDs 
    ON Arithmetics.ArithmeticID = ArithmeticsAndTypeIDs.ArithmeticsID
    INNER JOIN ArithmeticTypes 
    ON ArithmeticsAndTypeIDs.TypeID = ArithmeticTypes.TypeID
    WHERE UserID = 0
    AND
    ArithmeticTypes.TypeID = 2
    AND TimeStamp >= '09-21-2016 00:00:00'
    AND TimeStamp <= '09-22-2016 00:00:00'
```

**It should be noted that "@value2" contains the value ("09-21-2016 00:00:00") (assuming that's the date that is passed as a parameter), so I know that the formatting is correct.**

**Any help towards fixing this issue would be greatly appreciated :)**

Comment: Remove the single quote ' in '@value2' => `"AND TimeStamp >= @value2 "`. And in @value3 also

Comment: Adding single quotes around the parameter placeholder transform it in a literal string and of course there is no way to consider a string '@value1' as it was a date

Comment: Oh, so it's tryng to convert "@value2" into the datetime? That seems so logical now... Thanks! How can I get around this without opening up to SQL injections though?

Comment: That's right Sprouze. When you use parameters, you don't need to add quotes,just let the parameter do the magic

Comment: @Sprouze you don't need to convert anything, either the parameter name or the value. The parameter values are passed by the driver as binary values. Just pass `time` as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert parameters to strings. That's one of the main reason they are used instead of string concatenation. As long as `TimeStamp` is a date-related type, your query should be :

```
WHERE UserID = @value1 AND TimeStamp BETWEEN @value2 and @value3
```

Parameter values should be passed without any conversion to string:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", GetUserID(userLoggedIn));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", time);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value3", time.AddDays(1));
```

Parameters are passed by the driver itself in a binary form, so they don't have to be converted to text. This way you bypass any formatting or localization issues.

You also avoid SQL injection issues because the parameter values are never part of the query. Even string variables are treated as just text, they are never part of the query.